# Reading from a .txt file dynamically with Python

Tags: python, file

I have a text file that will be populated depending on a radio button selected by a user in php

I am reading from the same text file, whenever I find that a new line has been added the Python script prints it. For now I am just printing it. Eventually I will send out a message on a GSM modem based on the new records in the .txt file. Right now I'm just printing it to make sure I can identify a new record.

Here's the code I'm using. It works just fine.

```
def main():
    flag = 0
    count = 0
    while flag == 0:
        f = open('test.txt', 'r')
        with open('test.txt') as f:
            for i, l in enumerate(f):
                pass
        nol = i + 1
        if count < nol:
            while count <= nol:
                f = open('test.txt', 'r')
                a = f.readlines(count)
                if count == 0:
                    print a[0]
                    count = count+2
                else:
                    print a[count-1]
                    count = count+1
if __name__ ==  '__main__':
    main()
```

I was wondering if there is a better way to do this.

Also, php will keep writing to the file. And python will keep reading from it. Will this cause a clash? Since multiple instance are open?

Comment: Maybe this would be better suited for the codereview stackexchange?

Comment: possible duplicate of [tail -f in python with no time.sleep](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1475950/tail-f-in-python-with-no-time-sleep)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic; you might find answers at http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4690739/141343) answer you can use `watchdog` package to watch over changes in the file.  Alternatively you can use custom made [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/473471/141343) using `fcntl` in Unix.

First solution has advantage of being cross-platform.