# How to keep printing each new entry from a live file? Python

Tags: python

This prints out the last line of the file then stops. A new reading will be coming in a 1/2 second, but the program has already stopped. This is a live file with a new reading every 1/2 second. How do I get it to keep printing each new line?

```
with open('putty.log', 'rb') as fh:
    for line in fh:
        p = line.split(' ')
        first = next(fh).decode()
        fh.seek(-1024, 2)
        last = fh.readlines()[-1].decode()
        print last
```

Comment: use python crontab https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-crontab to run this script every .5 second i think that will do..

Comment: Also see [tail -f in python with no time.sleep](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1475950)

Comment: I now closed your last two questions by using simple and quick google searches. Please do some research before asking.

Comment: Thanks again Martijn. I'll do more research.