# Streaming text from a file while its been written to

Tags: python, stream, filestream

Is there a better and cleaner way to stream data from a text file as it been written to in real time?

At the moment im using a server to simulate data being written continuously and using seek() method to only read the most recently added data and the print it to the screen.

The problem Im having is testing if the file is been written to or not and if its not then to sleep for a short period then test if its been written to then
generate and output to print to the screen.

```
import time
seek1 = 198707
seek2 = 198719
file_open = open('C:\Users\Jay\Desktop\Tools\Uni-    Server\UniServerZ\core\\apache2\logs\\access.log')
#C:\Users\Jay\Desktop\Tools\Uni-Server\UniServerZ\core\apache2\logs
#C:\Users\Jay\PycharmProjects\Parsly\\access.log

def generate_list(read_lines):#properly build this with seek positional checks.
    #file_object.seek(seek_position)
    #lines = file_object.readlines()
    for i in read_lines:
        yield i


def seek_new_postion(generator):
    listt = []
    seek = file_open.tell()
    old_seek = None
    counter = 0
    while 1:
        if old_seek == seek and not counter == 5:
            print "sleeping"
            time.sleep(1)
            counter +=1
        else:
            p = generate_list(file_open.readlines())
            for i in p:
                print i
            time.sleep(1)
            print "___________________________"
            print "start seek: %s" % file_open.tell()
            print "old seek: %s" % old_seek
            print "___________________________"
            old_seek = seek
            seek = file_open.tell()
            counter = 0

print file_open.tell()
for i in seek_new_postion("test"):
print i
```

Comment: You may get some inspiration from http://stackoverflow.com/a/1476006/2375207

Comment: possible duplicate of [tail -f in python with no time.sleep](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1475950/tail-f-in-python-with-no-time-sleep)

Comment: There are some problems with your solution as you don't update `old_seek` or `seek` if they happens to be the same - the loop will just sleep for five seconds.

Comment: @skyking i couldn't work out how to change the seek and old_seek so i used  counter as a time out to try and read the file again from seek position.

Comment: @Jay Jamieson Actually the `seek` and `tell` is quite pointless and overworked solution. You would have to save current position, `seek` to the end and use `tell` to get the length of the file and then to restore the file position again with `seek` to the saved position. Instead you could just rely on the fact that `readlines` will return empty result if there is nothing more to be read from the file (yet).

Comment: @skyking I see what you mean, the reason i wanted to use seek is to have a write out file when the program exits so that when it gets started it will start from the last seeked position

Comment: @Jay Jamieson Then you'll do the same, but each time you read from it you either sleep (no lines returned) or get new position via `tell`. Then when you start next time you `seek` to the last position - a lot of telling, but not so much seeking.

Comment: Thanks, i found where i was going wrong, with the seek in part of the if statement.